# Is it too old to start a Physics PhD at 26?

Tags: phd

Is it too old to start a Physics PhD at 26 ? In average , How many PhD students in physics or mathematics who are older than 25 in their first year ?

Comment: Been 26 is not too old. But not knowing how to google "too old phd" or know how to search "too old" in this forum is too lazy.

Comment: Also see: the rest of the [tag:age] tag.

Comment: Hope not. I just started and I'm 28

Comment: ------------- 26 x No.

Answer (score 5):

In the US at least starting at 26 would still put you in one of the largest age groups.

Looking at the data from [the Council on Graduate Schools](http://www.cgsnet.org/ckfinder/userfiles/files/DataSources_2009_12.pdf) and the [University of British Columbia](https://www.grad.ubc.ca/about-us/graduate-education-analysis-research/demographics-age), for example, one can see that there is a good range of Doctoral students in their 20s and 30s. In fact a number of other sources quote a median range of [27](http://www.forbes.com/sites/joshfreedman/2013/09/20/the-typical-college-student-is-not-a-typical-college-student-and-other-fun-college-demographics-data/#144ba6ffc43a) to [34, for male, 32 for female](http://www.smh.com.au/national/postgraduate-education/are-you-a-typical-postgraduate-student-20150402-1mdkvx.html) - the last one seems to be the reason Google gives 33 as an answer if you search for "average age of a graduate student" in the US. So according to the data, you're actually a bit young.

As a personal example, I will be in my 30s when I start my Doctorate pursuit due to waiting until after my military service to focus on my academic career.